# BAD FILE MODE yum-cron

Tags: linux, files, cron, yum

Content of `service crond status -l`:

```
[root@test ~]# service crond status -l
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  -l crond.service
● crond.service - Command Scheduler
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-01-15 13:34:58 EST; 1 months 6 days 
ago
Main PID: 831 (crond)
CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
       └─831 /usr/sbin/crond -n


ORPHAN (no passwd entry)
(root) BAD FILE MODE (/etc/cron.d/yum-cron)
```

I'm getting the above error of cron status for yum-cron(BAD FILE MODE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cronie (the cron in question), does a specific check for file permissions on each crontab file, at:

https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie/blob/master/src/database.c#L96

The mask it uses is 533 and the resulting masked permissions must be 400, which means that it will allow read (4) or read/write (4+2) bits for the owner of the file, and no more than read (4) for group and other.

Some visual examples:

```
user-readable
=====
r w x - human-readable permissions
4 2 1 - permission bit values
1 0 0 - file permissions are: readable only
1 0 1 - a mask of 5
=====
1 0 0 - OK -- resulting masked bits (4)

user-readable and writable
=====
r w x - human-readable permissions
4 2 1 - permission bit values
1 1 0 - file permissions are: readable and writable
1 0 1 - a mask of 5
=====
1 0 0 - OK -- resulting masked bits (4)

user-executable
=====
r w x - human-readable permissions
4 2 1 - permission bit values
0 0 1 - file permissions are: executable only
1 0 1 - a mask of 5
=====
0 0 1 - FAIL -- resulting masked bits (1)

group (or other) - readable
r w x - human-readable permissions
4 2 1 - permission bit values
1 0 0 - file permissions are: readable only
0 1 1 - a mask of 3
=====
0 0 0 - OK -- resulting masked bits (0)

group (or other) - readable and writable
r w x - human-readable permissions
4 2 1 - permission bit values
1 1 0 - file permissions are: readable and writable
0 1 1 - a mask of 3
=====
0 1 0 - FAIL -- resulting masked bits (2)

group (or other) - no permissions
r w x - human-readable permissions
4 2 1 - permission bit values
0 0 0 - file permissions are: no permissions
0 1 1 - a mask of 3
=====
0 0 0 - OK -- resulting masked bits (0)
```

You most likely have writable-bits on the file somewhere; some possible fixes are:

```
chmod 400 /etc/cron.d/yum-cron
chmod 600 /etc/cron.d/yum-cron
chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/yum-cron
```

Reference:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html

Comment: I'm no longer getting bad file name but now when I check /var/spool/mail/root......./bin/sh: /etc/cron.d/0yum.cron:  says Permission denied

Comment: Perhaps we should wrap up this question (solved the bad file mode), and open a new question regarding the cron sh error.