# Permission denied yum-cron

Tags: linux, centos, files, cron, yum

Content of `/var/spool/mail/root`:

```
From root@test.corp.test.biz  Fri Feb 23 12:40:02 2018
Return-Path: <root@test.corp.test.biz>
X-Original-To: root
Delivered-To: root@test.corp.test.biz
Received: by test.corp.test.biz (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id 202C12C0A32; Fri, 23 Feb 2018 12:40:02 -0500 (EST)
From: root@test.corp.test.biz (Cron Daemon)
To: root@test.corp.test.biz
Subject: Cron <root@test> /etc/cron.d/0yum.cron > 
/etc/cron.d/0yum.cron.log
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=root>
Message-Id: <20180223174002.202C12C0A32@test.corp.test.biz>
Date: Fri, 23 Feb 2018 12:40:02 -0500 (EST)

/bin/sh: /etc/cron.d/0yum.cron: Permission denied
```

Permission of `/etc/cron.d/0yum.cron`:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4999 Feb 21 12:49 /etc/cron.d/0yum.cron
```

Contents of `/etc/cron.d/0yum.cron`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Only run if this flag file is set (by /etc/rc.d/init.d/yum-cron)
if [ ! -f /var/lock/subsys/yum-cron ]; then
exit 0
fi

DAILYSCRIPT=/etc/yum/yum-daily.yum
WEEKLYSCRIPT=/etc/yum/yum-weekly.yum
LOCKDIR=/var/lock/yum-cron.lock
LOCKFILE=$LOCKDIR/pidfile
TSLOCK=$LOCKDIR/ts.lock

# Grab config settings
if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/yum-cron ]; then
source /etc/sysconfig/yum-cron
fi
# set default for SYSTEMNAME
[ -z "$SYSTEMNAME" ]  && SYSTEMNAME=$(hostname)

# Only run on certain days of the week
dow=`date +%w`
DAYS_OF_WEEK=${DAYS_OF_WEEK:-0123456}
if [ "${DAYS_OF_WEEK/$dow/}" == "${DAYS_OF_WEEK}" ]; then
exit 0
fi

# if DOWNLOAD_ONLY is set then we force CHECK_ONLY too.
# Gotta check before one can download!
if [ "$DOWNLOAD_ONLY" == "yes" ]; then
CHECK_ONLY=yes
fi

YUMTMP=$(mktemp /var/run/yum-cron.XXXXXX)
touch $YUMTMP
[ -x /sbin/restorecon ] && /sbin/restorecon $YUMTMP

# Random wait function
random_wait() {
sleep $(( $RANDOM % ($RANDOMWAIT * 60) + 1 ))
}

# Note - the lockfile code doesn't try and use YUMTMP to email messages 
nicely.
# Too many ways to die, this gets handled by normal cron error mailing.
# Try mkdir for the lockfile, will test for and make it in one atomic action
if mkdir $LOCKDIR 2>/dev/null; then
# store the current process ID in there so we can check for staleness later
echo "$$" >"${LOCKFILE}"
# and clean up locks and tempfile if the script exits or is killed
trap "{ rm -f $LOCKFILE $TSLOCK; rmdir $LOCKDIR 2>/dev/null; rm -f $YUMTMP; 
exit 255; }" INT TERM EXIT
else
# lock failed, check if process exists.  First, if there's no PID file
# in the lock directory, something bad has happened, we can't know the
# process name, so clean up the old lockdir and restart
if [ ! -f $LOCKFILE ]; then
rmdir $LOCKDIR 2>/dev/null
echo "yum-cron: no lock PID, clearing and restarting myself" >&2
exec $0 "$@"
  fi
  OTHERPID="$(cat "${LOCKFILE}")"
  # if cat wasn't able to read the file anymore, another instance probably 
  is
  # about to remove the lock -- exit, we're *still* locked
  if [ $? != 0 ]; then
  echo "yum-cron: lock failed, PID ${OTHERPID} is active" >&2
  exit 0
  fi
  if ! kill -0 $OTHERPID &>/dev/null; then
  # lock is stale, remove it and restart
  echo "yum-cron: removing stale lock of nonexistant PID ${OTHERPID}" >&2
  rm -rf "${LOCKDIR}"
  echo "yum-cron: restarting myself" >&2
  exec $0 "$@"
  else
  # Remove stale (more than a day old) lockfiles
  find $LOCKDIR -type f -name 'pidfile' -amin +1440 -exec rm -rf $LOCKDIR \;
  # if it's still there, it wasn't too old, bail
  if [ -f $LOCKFILE ]; then
    # lock is valid and OTHERPID is active - exit, we're locked!
    echo "yum-cron: lock failed, PID ${OTHERPID} is active" >&2
    exit 0
  else
    # lock was invalid, restart
    echo "yum-cron: removing stale lock belonging to stale PID ${OTHERPID}" 
  >&2
    echo "yum-cron: restarting myself" >&2
    exec $0 "$@"
  fi
fi
fi

# Then check for updates and/or do them, as configured
{
# First, if this is CLEANDAY, do so
CLEANDAY=${CLEANDAY:-0}
if [ ! "${CLEANDAY/$dow/}" == "${CLEANDAY}" ]; then
  /usr/bin/yum $YUM_PARAMETER -e ${ERROR_LEVEL:-0} -d ${DEBUG_LEVEL:-0} -y 
shell $WEEKLYSCRIPT
fi

# Now continue to do the real work
if [ "$CHECK_ONLY" == "yes" ]; then
random_wait
touch $TSLOCK
/usr/bin/yum $YUM_PARAMETER -e 0 -d 0 -y check-update 1> /dev/null 2>&1
case $? in
  1)   exit 1;;
  100) echo "New updates available for host `/bin/hostname`";
       /usr/bin/yum $YUM_PARAMETER -e ${ERROR_LEVEL:-0} -d ${DEBUG_LEVEL:-0} 
-y -C check-update
       if [ "$DOWNLOAD_ONLY" == "yes" ]; then
           /usr/bin/yum $YUM_PARAMETER -e ${ERROR_LEVEL:-0} -d 
${DEBUG_LEVEL:-0} -y --downloadonly update
           echo "Updates downloaded, use \"yum -C update\" manually to 
install them."
       fi
       ;;
esac
elif [ "$CHECK_FIRST" == "yes" ]; then
# Don't run if we can't access the repos
random_wait
touch $TSLOCK
/usr/bin/yum $YUM_PARAMETER -e 0 -d 0 check-update 2>&-
case $? in
  1)   exit 1;;
  100) /usr/bin/yum $YUM_PARAMETER -e ${ERROR_LEVEL:-0} -d ${DEBUG_LEVEL:-0} 
-y update yum
       /usr/bin/yum $YUM_PARAMETER -e ${ERROR_LEVEL:-0} -d ${DEBUG_LEVEL:-0} 
-y shell $DAILYSCRIPT
       ;;
esac
else
random_wait
touch $TSLOCK
/usr/bin/yum $YUM_PARAMETER -e ${ERROR_LEVEL:-0} -d ${DEBUG_LEVEL:-0} -y 
update yum
/usr/bin/yum $YUM_PARAMETER -e ${ERROR_LEVEL:-0} -d ${DEBUG_LEVEL:-0} -y 
shell $DAILYSCRIPT
fi
} >> $YUMTMP 2>&1

if [ ! -z "$MAILTO" ] && [ -x /bin/mail ]; then
# if MAILTO is set, use mail command (ie better than standard mail with cron 
output)
[ -s "$YUMTMP" ] && mail -r "$MAIL_FROM" -s "System update: $SYSTEMNAME" 
$MAILTO < $YUMTMP
else
# default behavior is to use cron's internal mailing of output from cron-
script
cat $YUMTMP
fi
rm -f $YUMTMP

exit 0
```

I'm getting the above permission denied for my yum script. This could possibly relate to my last question here: [BAD FILE MODE yum-cron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425686/bad-file-mode-yum-cron)

Comment: Please add the contents of `/etc/cron.d/0yum.cron`and tell us wether you are using SELinux

Comment: What is the question being asked here?

Comment: It looks to me like you have set up a cron job to ... *run* the cron file. If you have a script that you'd like to have cron run, it'd be a little odd to put it in /etc/cron.d.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I added the contents of /etc/cron.d/0yum.cron and SELinux is enabled/enforced.

Comment: @aliceinpalth Why am I getting permission denied?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Where should I put the script?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want that script run daily, put it in in /etc/cron.daily; if you have it in your own crontab, put it in /usr/local/bin or anywhere you like *except* under /etc/cron* directories, which cron is already expecting to execute.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I want to run this script daily at 11am M-F and have a email sent.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro any feedback?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I put the script into cron.daily but I'm still getting permission denied from /var/spool/mail/root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in /etc/cron.d/ should be *cron entries*, not scripts. That's why your previous question, [BAD FILE MODE yum-cron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425686/bad-file-mode-yum-cron), showed cron complaining; it expected a plain text file (not an executable script) containing crontab entries.

That's why, for example, I have a file named `/etc/cron.d/0hourly` which contains:

```
# Run the hourly jobs
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
```

Since you have a *script*, I'd recommend placing it in one of the /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.weekly, or /etc/cron.monthly directories and ensuring that it's executable there (for example, `chmod u+x /etc/cron.daily/0yum.cron`).

Comment: Thanks Jeff, one last question do I need to specify the SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root also?

Comment: Those are just examples from my version of the file in /etc/cron.d; you're not putting your script there.